# Run a script when docker is stopped

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to create docker container using dockerfile where script-entry.sh is to be executed when the containers starts and script-exit.sh to be executed when the container stops.

ENTRYPOINT helped to accomplish the first part of the problem where script-entry.sh runs on startup.

How will i make sure the script-exit.sh is executed on docker exit/stop ?

Comment: Docker daemon logs everything, why not write a script/program that parse the logs and, when the even containerID stops appears execute the script you want to.

Comment: @Auzias There is an [event api](https://gliderlabs.com/blog/2015/04/14/docker-events-explained/) and an [`events`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/events/) command built into docker that would be better suited to tasks like that

Comment: @Auzias also running a something after the stop event will likely not be able to run or get interrupted.

Comment: To run a script on the _host_ when a container exits, see https://superuser.com/questions/1464366/docker-how-to-launch-a-script-on-host-when-container-stops

Answer (score 20):

`docker stop` sends a `SIGTERM` signal to the main process running inside the Docker container (the entry script). So you need a way to catch the signal and then trigger the exit script.

See [This link](https://medium.com/@gchudnov/trapping-signals-in-docker-containers-7a57fdda7d86#.6b04xvnr8) for explanation on signal trapping and an example (near the end of the page)

Answer (score -6):

Create a script, and save it as a bash file, that contains that following:

```
$CONTAINER_NAME="someNameHere"
docker exec -it $CONTAINER_NAME bash -c "sh script-exit.sh"
docker stop $CONTAINER_NAME
```

Run that file instead of running `docker stop`, and that should do the trick.  You can setup an alias for that as well.

As for automating it inside of Docker itself, I've never seen it done before.  Good luck figuring it out, if that's the road you want to take.

Comment: It does not answer the question. The question is: "how to execute a script once a container is stopped", which is different from "how to execute a script and then stop the container"