# How can I execute a command/script after issuing "docker container stop" command?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-entrypoint

I would like a container to run a determined command before it stops after issuing the command "docker container stop". I have found the question [How to execute a script when I terminate a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41451159/how-to-execute-a-script-when-i-terminate-a-docker-container) but it does not really work as the container keeps crashing after creating it, even if I add an infinite loop to execute when run.
I'm running the container as: docker run -ti -d --name test stop_test

What could be wrong?

This is my docker file:

```
#Starting with a ubuntu image
FROM ubuntu

#Installing all dependencies

#Copying files
COPY loop.sh .
COPY commands.sh .
COPY stop.sh .

#Running new container
RUN chmod +x commands.sh
RUN chmod +x stop.sh
CMD ["./commands.sh"]

#Adding Entrypoint
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "./stop.sh" ]
```

The stop script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Defining cleanup procedure
cleanup() {
    echo "Container stopped. Running script..."
}

#Trapping the SIGTERM
trap 'cleanup' SIGTERM

#Execute a command
less /etc/password &

#Wait
wait $!

#Cleanup
cleanup
```

The loop script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
 sleep 300
done
```

The commands script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

./loop.sh
```

Comment: is not it the solution?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35808251/run-a-script-when-docker-is-stopped

Comment: From what I understand one of the answers links to some examples where they recommend using a script. That's what I'm doing, but container crashes.

Comment: What do you mean by crashes? What output and logs do you receive?

Comment: It's been solved! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the command being executed by the *stop.sh* script. I replaced it by the infinite loop script and worked well.

Comment: please share your solution code